# Get update of width and height

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Can I update the width and height of rect that shows on HTML?
because rect can be scaling width and height so I want it to update too but I have no idea how. is there any solution?

```
<html>
<canvas id="c" width="900" height="720"></canvas>
<p id="show"></p>
<button onclick="addRect2()">Rect</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>

</html>
```

JS

```
var width;
var height;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
window.addRect2 = function(width,height){
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'black',
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
});
canvas.add(rect);
width = rect.width;
height = rect.height;
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Width and Height" + width " " + height;}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("c").style.width = "300px"; ` From [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var width,height;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'black',
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
});
canvas.add(rect);
var el = document.getElementById("show");
displayDim();

rect.on('modified',function(){
 displayDim();
})

rect.on('scaling',function(){
 displayDim();
})

function displayDim(){
  width = parseInt(rect.width * rect.scaleX);
  height = parseInt(rect.height * rect.scaleY);
  el.innerHTML = "Width: " + width + "px and Height: " + height+"px";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
<p id="show"></p>
```

Use [events](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events), while `scaling`/`modified` update the width/height. To get height/width after scaling, you need to multiply with scaleY/scaleX respectively.

Comment: May I ask again, why do we need to multiply with scaleY/scaleX ?

Comment: that width/height doesn't change, while scaling only scaleX/scaleY changes. That's why need to multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Try with these JS code. make sure to import fabric.js library to your html code.

```js
var width;
var height;
window.addRect2 = function(width,height){
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'black',
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
});
canvas.add(rect);
width = rect.width;
height = rect.height;
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Width and Height" + width + " " + height;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="900" height="720"></canvas>
<p id="show"></p>
<button onclick="addRect2()">Rect</button>
```